# Wordpress gatsby graphql need sorting on children

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby

On the following graphql I need sorting/order on the WPChildren with the 'menuOrder' item...

```
query ($id: String!) {
  allWpPage(
    filter: {id: {eq: $id}}
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        uri
        content
        children {
          id
        }
        blocks
      }
    }
    nodes {
      wpChildren {
        nodes {
          id
          ... on WpPage {
            id
            title
            uri
            featuredImage {
              node {
                mediaItemUrl
              }
            }
            overviewtext {
              overviewTitle
              overviewDescription
            }
            menuOrder
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The graphql is to show content from current page AND gets its children but I can't get the sorting to work...any ideas are highly appreciated! :)

regards,

Chris